# AWS ECS Latency Issue with API Requests to Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, delay

I am encountering a persistent latency issue with API requests to a load balancer in my AWS environment. Despite my efforts to troubleshoot the problem, I have been unable to find a resolution thus far.

**Infrastructure Details:**

- ECS Service: The API requests are directed to an ECS service in my environment. ECS services has a task with container that contains HTTP server.
- ECS Container: The ECS service runs a containerized application
  responsible for handling the API requests.
- Load Balancer: A load balancer is configured to distribute incoming
  traffic across multiple instances of the ECS container.
- Listener: The load balancer is set up with appropriate listeners to
  receive and forward incoming requests to the target group.
- Target Group: The load balancer routes the requests to a target group
  associated with the ECS container instances.
- TLS: The load balancer has the SSL/TLS connections using Certificate Manager and
  communicates with the ECS container over HTTP.
- DNS: The load balancer is accessed using a DNS name, which is
  properly configured with the appropriate DNS records on the Route53 side.
- I made all security group and target group rules to accept any inbound/outbound traffic.

**Issue Description:**

When making API requests to the load balancer, the first request consistently experiences a delay of approximately 76 seconds before receiving a response. Subsequent requests made within a short time frame are processed without any noticeable delay. However, after a period of inactivity (around 5-10 minutes), the first request again encounters the same 76-second delay.

Also, if I'm trying to call API endpoints via curl it always delayed with 76s delay.

**Environment Details:**

- Load Balancer: AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB)
- Target Group: Configured with appropriate health checks and routing rules
- Backend Service: An ECS container running a websockets server
- AWS Region: us-east-1
- Security Groups: Allowing inbound traffic for HTTP/HTTPS and all protocols
- DNS: Configured with appropriate DNS records pointing to the load balancer

**Troubleshooting Steps Performed:**

- Verified DNS resolution: Successfully resolved the DNS name to the correct load balancer IP address.
- Checked load balancer configuration: Ensured that the load balancer is correctly configured with the appropriate listeners, target groups, and routing rules.
- Checked backend service health: Confirmed that the ECS container running the websockets server is healthy and responding to requests normally.
- Analyzed load balancer logs: Reviewed ALB access logs and observed consistent 76-second delays for the first request, while subsequent requests were processed without delay.
- Increased resources: Adjusted the CPU and memory allocation for the ECS container (to 2 CPU and 4 GB RAM) to rule out any resource constraints, but the issue persisted.
- Verified connectivity: Confirmed that there are no network connectivity issues or packet loss by performing traceroute and tcptraceroute to the load balancer's IP address.

**Additional Information:**

- The issue is specific to API requests to the load balancer. Other services, such as S3 and CloudFront, using the same DNS name but with a different subdomain, are functioning normally without any latency issues.
- The issue occurs consistently and has been observed over an extended period, ruling out sporadic or intermittent network problems.
- There are no reported errors or warnings in the AWS Management Console related to the load balancer or ECS service.

Comment: The issue is with your application taking too much time to process the requests. You need to add logs to your application to narrow down where the issue is. Are you using a database? This sounds like the kind of thing I would expect to see if I was using Aurora Serverless v1 as my database.

Comment: I deployed a simple Node.js server application with a single endpoint, and I still encountered the same 76-second delay for the first request. Subsequent requests, within a short time frame, are processed without any noticeable delay. This behavior persists even when the application has minimal processing logic and does not interact with a database.

Comment: What do the logs in that simple Node.JS server indicate is happening during that time? You should be logging when you receive the request, and when you return the response, and then looking at the timestamps to determine if the slowdown is happening on the ECS side.

Comment: I did check the logs on the Node.js server side, and it seems that the delay between receiving the request and returning the response is actually just a few milliseconds. So, it looks like the application itself is handling the requests pretty quickly.

Based on this, my hunch is that the latency issue I'm facing is not due to the application code. It seems to be more related to the infrastructure or some configuration issue that goes beyond the application's scope.

Comment: OK, that is key information that should have been included in the question. Can you now clarify this? "Reviewed ALB access logs and observed consistent 76-second delays for the first request" What are the `request_processing_time`, `target_processing_time`, and `response_processing_time` values in the ALB access logs?